# issue with DateTime at 01/01/001

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm doing ASP.NET App and I've trouble with datetime.

When I select 31th of march DateTime get into model in controller is 01/01/0001, buth when I select 1st of march, no error.

I want to use this format: day/month/year, I think DateTime Default format for the app is month/date/year, and this is why, so How can I make this work?

Here is what I did:

Model:

```
public DateTime dateAudit { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<input class="form-controlform-control datefield" id="dateAudit" name="dateAudit" value="@Model.dateAudit.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" />

$(".datefield").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                showTimePicker: false
            });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(AuditViewModel model)
            {...}
```

config file:

```
<globalization uiCulture="fr-FR" />
```

The 01/01/0001 is into model.date property when submitting the form.

What should be the best solution in order to have right dates?
Set global culture in order to use that kind of date? Something else?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a localization issue I had onece. Although you have specified your desired date format.

Comment: I've put <globalization uiCulture="fr-FR" /> in config file

Comment: When sending dates across the wire, I tend to prefer YYYY-mm-dd as this can be consistently interpreted between US and non-US cultures.

Comment: maybe but I have to show date as day/monhth/year

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following attribute to you date property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime dateAudit { get; set; }
```

Edited:

I just noticed another thing the might be adding on to the problem you are facing:

```
$(".datefield").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',**
                showTimePicker: false
            });
```

The `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'` should ideally be `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please see if correcting the dateFormat fixes you problem, update my answer.

Comment: Thanks but MM gives me "20/March/2015", not 20/03/2015, but model binding is OK... How can I use 20/03/2015 in the UI and make the model binding work?

Comment: I did not ask you to use MM, mm is correct only you had yy instead of yyyy.

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy gives me 20/03/20152015

Answer (score -1):

Change mm to MM because it will take minutes instead of Month.

```
$(".datefield").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yy',
                showTimePicker: false
            });
```

Comment: MM gives me "20/March/2015", not 20/03/2015... but it resolves the issue of model binding... by creating another issue, how cna I show 20/03/2015 in the UI? Thank you!

Comment: @Likesch: thanks but mm - month of year (two digit) makes my model binder crasy

Comment: try changing to this format. dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',

Comment: thanks again but model binder doesntt appreciate neither